# Understand RtlMoveMemory

Tags: vba

Thanks for reading this. I'm trying to understand this one out of curiosity. I copied this code from somewhere, try to mess around but it does not work as expected. I expect `Debug.Print c` to return 4, but it stays 3. I suspect the error could be in data type but not sure, as no error popup.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias _
            "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As LongPtr, ByRef Source As LongPtr, _
            ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#Else
    Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias _
           "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Long, Source As Long, _
            ByVal Length As Long)
#End If

Sub Main2()
    Dim c As Long, d As Long

    c = 3
    Move2 VarPtr(c)
    Debug.Print c

End Sub

Sub Move2(ByVal pointerOfi As LongPtr)
    Dim tempvalue As Long

    CopyMemory VarPtr(tempvalue), pointerOfi, LenB(pointerOfi)
    tempvalue = tempvalue + 1
    CopyMemory pointerOfi, VarPtr(tempvalue), LenB(pointerOfi)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to pass one arg byVal?

Comment: Yes it seems so, just my shallow understanding of there concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration of `CopyMemory`'s arguments does not include the `ByVal` keyword so all arguments are passed by reference (`ByRef`), this means that here:

```
CopyMemory VarPtr(tempvalue), pointerOfi, LenB(pointerOfi)
```

`CopyMemory` is passed a reference (the address) of the two long values that are the *result* of evaluating `VarPtr(tempvalue)` & `pointerOfi`,  rather than the actual values those variables contain.

If you have a variable that contains a memory address then you need to pass the value itself rather than the address of the variable containing the value:

```
CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(tempvalue), ByVal pointerOfi, LenB(pointerOfi)
```

Note that you can take advantage of `ByRef` and not worry about raw pointers at all:

```
Sub Main2()
    Dim c As Long, d As Long
    
    c = 3
    Move2 c
    Debug.Print c
End Sub

Sub Move2(x As Long)
    Dim tempvalue As Long

    CopyMemory tempvalue, x, LenB(tempvalue)
    tempvalue = tempvalue + 1
    CopyMemory x, tempvalue, LenB(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I misunderstand the `byVal` and `byRef`, thinking that they return the same value, but `byVal` creates another physical location in memory, while `byRef` points exactly to the one location.